# Define negating pcase patterns

Tags: elisp-macros, pcase

I am interested in extending `pcase` with patterns which:

1. Complement an existing pattern, e.g. `(not (pred string-empty-p))`. Such a pattern would match where the non-negated form does not match and vice versa.
2. Match when a predicate applied to the object being matched returns `nil`, e.g. `(npred (string= "foo"))`.

The following is my first attempt at the former:

```el
(pcase-defmacro not (pat)
  (let ((obj (make-symbol "obj")))
    `(and ,obj (guard (not (pcase ,obj (,pat)))))))
```

I would appreciate any suggestions for improvement of (1) (e.g. how to avoid a nested `pcase`) and implementation approaches for (2). Are there any conditions under which such patterns would be a bad idea (other than there being a better, non-`pcase` alternative)? Is there an idiomatic/elegant way of achieving the same effect which does not involve defining new `pcase` patterns?

#### Update

I think the `pred` pattern is constrained enough to allow for the following implementation for (2):

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))

(pcase-defmacro npred (pat)
  (let ((obj (make-symbol "obj")))
    `(and ,obj (guard (not (thread-last ,obj ,pat))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it right, then you need to reimplement `pcase` following the design of Racket's `match` more closely.  I didn't do that, because this generates code which uses local `lambda` definitions fairly extensively, which Elisp's compiler sadly handles rather poorly.

If you look at the end of `pcase--u1` you'll see some left-over handling of such a `not` pattern, which used to work for some cases, along with a comment giving some vague explanation for possible way to improve it (but currently, this never works anyway).

**Update**

What will be Emacs 28 has gained support for a very limited subset of negation in the form of `(pred (not FUN))`.  For example:

```el
(pcase "foo" ((pred (not (string= "bar"))) 'yes)) ;; => yes
```

Comment: Thank you for the interesting background and pointer; I intend to have a closer look when I find the time.